# Выдаёт ошибку во время генерирования токена

Tags: node.js, typescript

Если записать данные без .env, то всё работает исправно, в другом случае выдаёт ошибку

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import prisma from '../middleware/prisma-middleware'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

class TokenService{
    generateTokens(payload:any){
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload,process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET, {expiresIn:'30s'})
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET, {expiresIn:'30d'})
        return {
            accessToken,
            refreshToken
        }
    }
}
export default new TokenService()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша IDE подсказывает ошибку из-за того, что данные из `process.env` имеют тип `string | undefined`, а на стороне библиотеки jwt ожидается

```
export type Secret =
    | string
    | Buffer
    | KeyObject
    | { key: string | Buffer; passphrase: string }
```

Undefined не подходит.

Добавьте проверку входящих значений и используйте [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (**JWT_ACCESS_SECRET!**), чтобы "подтвердить" typescript, что переменная будет определена.

Например, так:

```typescript
import assert from 'node:assert';

import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

class TokenService {
  generateTokens(payload: any) {
    const { JWT_ACCESS_SECRET, JWT_REFRESH_SECRET } = process.env;
    assert(!!JWT_ACCESS_SECRET && !!JWT_REFRESH_SECRET);

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      payload,
      JWT_ACCESS_SECRET!,
      { expiresIn: '30s' }
    );
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
      payload,
      JWT_REFRESH_SECRET!,
      { expiresIn: '30d' }
    );
    return {
      accessToken,
      refreshToken
    };
  }
}

export default new TokenService();
```